# File Writer not writing no error in code

Tags: java

Ok I've written this code multiple time but for some reason it's not creating a text file in the location

```
public static void sauve(String a , String b , int c , String d , int f ) {
  int i;
  try {      
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\Desktop\\result.txt");              
    BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter(fw);     
    bw.write("Name : " +d);     
    bw.newLine();     
    bw.write("question number : "+ f);    
    bw.newLine();    
    bw.write("start time "+ a);    
    bw.newLine();    
    bw.write("Score : "+ c);    
    bw.newLine();    
    bw.write("finish time "+ b);    
    bw.close();     
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error "+e);
  }
}
```

Comment: your code is right, maybe some permissions problem or invalid path?

Comment: What I found weird is that I tried it on another PC and it worked, can't understand why it didn't work on my pc
I also tried printwriter still not working

Comment: Change double slashes to /

Comment: What is the exception you are seeing in your console?

Comment: no exception.
changed double slash to / nothing

Comment: are you able to create the same file manually in that location?  Did you compare the java version in your machine with  the other machine?

Comment: all the same. yes i can create manually the file

Answer (score 0):

If you really want your app to be cross platform, you should use `File.separator` or better, get use to URL's (`new Url("path/in/unix/form/file.ext")`), and if you want the users default directory you can just use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "desktop"
```